# spanning tree at layer 3

Tags: lan, spanning-tree, protocol-theory, wan, layer3

we want to prevent loops in the network be it LAN or WAN. However for layer 2 LAN networks STP is used to prevent looping switches.
However at layer 3 TTL field is used.
why not use STP for layer 3 too ?

Comment: Layer-3 loops are actually pretty rare because routing protocols have loop prevention built in. It is possible to override some, e.g. split-horizon, but you better know what you are doing.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Layer 3 has no issue with loops, on the contrary, the very purpose of the ARPANET (which eventually became the Internet) was to have a meshed network, resilient to attacks (I.E. where the loss of a node doesn't impact the overall network).

Actually the more "loops" you have in your network at layer 3, the more robust the network is.

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of the question.  He isn't asserting that layer3 networks should not have loops; he wants to know why spanning tree isn't used to manage the loops

Answer (score 1):

First things first you need to remember that IP and Ethernet were different protocols designed by different people to fill different needs. I know vendors like to use the terms "layer 2" and "layer 3" as if the protocols were part of some consistent protocol stack but they doesn't mean they really are.

Ethernet was designed to provide local networking in a building or maybe a campus. Traditional Ethernet networks were essentially a bus, repeaters/hubs/bridges/switches extended this to a tree.

However trees are bad from a performance and reliability point of view, the bridges/switches in the center of the network become a bottleneck and a single point of failure. The bigger the network gets the worse this becomes.

STP goes some way towards solving the reliability issues. Link aggregation goes some way towards solving the performance issues but overall it is still a lousy way to build large networks. Thanks to STP disabling links large ammounts of capacity sits idle and packets frequently take much longer routes than needed to get to their destination and if the STP root fails then reprecussings may be seen across the whole network.

IP was designed for interconnecting multiple networks at least one of which (the ARPANET) already had multiple sites. Trying to force the network into a tree would have made little sense. Instead IP networks rely on a combination of staticly defined routes and routing protocols to determine where data should be sent.

The "TTL" is a safety valve to stop misrouted packets looping forever. It should not be reaching zero in normal operation.

Interestingly the scalability problems with Ethernet along with a desire for large, geographically spread out Ethernet domains (for example to allow seamless VM migrations between datacenters) have lead to people running Ethernet on top of other protocols. The new hotness seems to be to encapsulate the Ethernet frames in UDP packets using VXLAN and then use BGP to control where they are sent.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to build a spanning tree on layer 3 simply because each packet can take a different path from source to destination; this is by design.

The mechanism that prevents a packet from looping forever in a layer 3 network (which should never happen unless there's a routing error) is, as you've mentioned, the Time To Live field (TTL) whose value is reduced by 1 at each hop.